# Ao mudar select chamar executar pesquisa

Tags: php, jquery

Estou tentando alterar um script que tenho para previsão do tempo, mas sem sucesso, hoje o usuário seleciona uma opção no select e clica no botão para executar a busca, o que estou tentando fazer é usar o OnChange para encurtar a operação.

O que tentei sem sucesso foi isso:

```
onchange="document.getElementById('frmBusca')
```

O script está assim hoje:

```
<form id="frmBusca" class="sky-form clearfix" action="" method="post">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="fancy-form fancy-form-select">
            <select name="Cidade" class="form-control" id="Cidade" tabindex="1" >
                <option value="0">Cidade</option>
                <?php foreach ($ResCidade as $Cidade) { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $Cidade->IdCidade; ?>"><?php echo $Cidade->Descricao; ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select>
            <i class="fancy-arrow"></i> </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <button class="btn btn-primary  pull-right btn-block">PESQUISAR</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
</div>
```

O está que está sendo invocado:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// BUSCA DADOS DO CLIMA
$(function() {      
    $("#frmBusca").validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {             
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'pBuscaClima.php',
                data: data,
                dataType: 'html',                   
                success: function(response)

                    // EXIBINDO O RETORNO DAS INFORMAÇÕES   
                     $("#msgClima").html(response);
                    // RESETANDO A FUNÇÃO
                    // _toggle();

                    $('#frmBusca').each(function() {
                        this.reset();
                    });             


                },
                error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    console.log(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError);
                    $("#msgClima").html('<div class="alert alert-danger fade in"><button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button><i class="fa-fw fa fa-times"></i><strong>ATENÇÃO!</strong> Ocorreu um erro ao tentar enviar a pergunta. Contate o suporte técnico.</div>');
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Você precisa desta função no validate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando houver o evento `change` no select, pegue o valor e envia via ajax:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// BUSCA DADOS DO CLIMA   

$(document).on('change', '#Cidade', function(){  

    let cidade = $('#Cidade option:selected').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'pBuscaClima.php',
        data: {Cidade: cidade},
        dataType: 'html',                   
        success: function(response){

            // EXIBINDO O RETORNO DAS INFORMAÇÕES   
             $("#msgClima").html(response);
            // RESETANDO A FUNÇÃO
            // _toggle();

            $('#frmBusca').each(function() {
                this.reset();
            });             


        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            console.log(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError);
            $("#msgClima").html('<div class="alert alert-danger fade in"><button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button><i class="fa-fw fa fa-times"></i><strong>ATENÇÃO!</strong> Ocorreu um erro ao tentar enviar a pergunta. Contate o suporte técnico.</div>');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Obrigado pela excelente dica @Alisson Acioli, valeu.

Answer (score 1):

O seu OnChange tem que ser no Select e não no Form.

Fiz um exemplo para sua referência assim:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

</head>

    <body>
        <form>
            <div>
                <select name="Cidade" id="Cidade" tabindex="1" onchange="BuscaClima()" >
                    <option value="0">Cidade</option>
                    <option value="1">BH</option>
                    <option value="2">SP</option>
                    <option value="2">RIO</option>
                    <!--...-->
                </select>
                <div id="demo"></div>
            </div>
        </form>


        <script type="text/javascript">
            function BuscaClima() {
                //Exemplo
                var x = document.getElementById("Cidade").value;
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You selected: " + x;

                //Chama sua function BuscaClima
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'pBuscaClima.php',
                    data: data,
                    dataType: 'html',                   
                    success: function(response){
                        $("#msgClima").html(response);
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        console.log(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError);
                        $("#msgClima").html('<div class="alert alert-danger fade in"><button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button><i class="fa-fw fa fa-times"></i><strong>ATENÇÃO!</strong> Ocorreu um erro ao tentar enviar a pergunta. Contate o suporte técnico.</div>');
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Valeu @Bruno Heringer, sua ajuda colaborou demais.